Ruby code not showing up after I run it on VSCode?
I've been trying to learn Ruby programming language from the tutorial of freecodecamp but found out that Atom is basically dead. So I decided to use VSCode, everything goes well until I get to the part where I have to ask for user input. When I run it, nothing appears on the terminal.
Mind you, I'm very new to all of this. What can I try next?


It looks like you're using the Windows Powershell terminal. That might work; have you tried running ruby userinput.rb?

You could also try Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which may be much easier to get things running in. But try the above command first.

It doesn't look like anything ran. What did you do to run the program?

I run it fine by (in the terminal)
ruby userinput.rb

What are you using to run your sourecode?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you are using VSCode, you need to install:

Ruby language on your Windows box

Ruby extensions for VSCode

Once you get this working, open the "Explorer" widget on the left side of VSCode so you can see the files.

Right click on the Ruby file userinput.rb and choose "Open in Integrated Terminal"

Once in the terminal, run it like so:
ruby userinput.rb


Hope this helps!
